# Null-homolog loop in region

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $A$ be open, connected set in $\mathbb{C}$. We know that if a $\alpha$ loop is null-homotopic in $A$ then it is null-homolog. Is the converse true?

Comment: I don't know the answer for open, connected subsets of $\mathbb{C}$, but in general, the answer is no.  See, for example, the Poincare dodecahedral space.